# Is it possible to add a GLSurfaceView to ViewGroup without making screen go black

Tags: android

I have a ViewGroup (V) that is the Activity's content view and I draw on the V's Canvas directly. At runtime, I create a GLSurfaceView (G) whose initial content is set to be the same as the V. Then I call V.addView(G) to add G to the top of V. I expect this to be a smooth transition and users should not notice any artifacts. However, during the transition, the screen goes black for about half a second and then G shows up. I am not sure why it is so and is there any way to get rid of this effect?

Best Regards,
Frank